# sort php json data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to sort php json data from multidimensional array using javascript or jquery
my php is

```
$array = array();
$x = 0;
while($row = $get_images->fetch_assoc()){
    $name = $row['name'];
    $image_type = $row['image_type'];
    $caption = stripslashes($row['caption']);
    $arr = array('name' => $name, 'type' => $image_type, 'caption' => $caption);
    $array[] = $arr;
    //array_push($array, $$arr);
    $x++;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

the result looks like this:

```
[{"name":"2323dffd","type":"jpg","caption":"ddd"},{"name":"323232323","type":"jpg","caption":"dddfdf"},{"name":"dffdd","type":"jpg","caption":"dfdfdfere"}]
```

I want append the data to a document prefebly using a while loop in javascript but I am not sure how to use the data from the json file (I am not sure if it is valid). I tried some solutions such as $.each but they did not work. This is my JS:

$(function($){

```
    $.getJSON("http://www.xxxxx.com/json.php", function(json) {
        while(){
                      //your code here
                      $("#content").append(json...);
                    }
    });
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how your `$.each()` doesn't work, but this will work fine.

```
$.each(json, function(i,obj){
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Where obj will be:

```
{"name":"2323dffd","type":"jpg","caption":"ddd"}
```

And you can do

```
console.log(obj.name);
```

and so on.

Further, here's a [jsFiddle illustrating your JSON iteration](http://jsfiddle.net/9bRkg/).